# Rich Chart on iOS - BB - Android with similar look and feel

Tags: android, iphone, blackberry, charts

I am looking for a chart library that is available for BB(OS >=5 ), Android(OS >= 2.3) and IOS(OS >= 4). I have two requirements

1. Chart should be attractive (not basic like drawn by canvas)
2. look & feel should be same on all platforms.

I have tried many web based frameworks for generating chart but they mostly support higher OS version as they use HTML5 and javascript. I have explored,

1. HighCharts
2. Sencha Charts
3. Fusion Charts
4. Flotr
5. and many more...

But all of them do not support BB OS 5. I have googled for native chart API that support BB OS 5 and above but didnt find anything. And whichever I found, they are very basic and not attractive in look. Also, it should be touch compatible and zoom-panning enabled. (like drill down etc..) so I can manipulate its event and show effect on graph. Is there any good suggestions if I am missing any chart or framework that I can use?

Comment: I found something for the chart... I haven;t go in to much details, but check it may be it is useful http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/aicharts.aspx
and http://www.kidroid.com/kichart/ (Commercial):- http://www.keepedge.com/products/android_charting/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there is any One  **native open source library** available for all platform  which provide you **same look and feel except**  you use open Google chart for all platform .

if you want to make it same you should customize every library .

Here is some of good open source library for

**Android:**

[AChartEngine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)

whcih support huge range of 2D chart like , line chart
area chart,
scatter chart,
time chart,
bar chart,
pie chart,
bubble chart,
doughnut chart,
range (high-low) bar chart,
dial chart / gauge,
combined (any combination of line, cubic line, scatter, bar, range bar, bubble) chart
cubic line chart.

**ios :**

[core-plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/feeds)

which can be customize same as like achart engine  with same look and feel .

**blackberry:**

there no such **rich** library availbe for blackberry for chart but you can manage to render a graph using some  library (Honestly i am  not huge fan of it ) like 
[aiCharts](http://www.artfulbits.com/products/blackberry/aicharts.aspx) or using some J2ME lib. like 
[Tazzix](http://tazzix.com/wp/2004/03/02/j2me-chart-graph-api-v09/) , [MIDP2.0](http://www.beanizer.org/site/index.php/en/Software/J2me-ChartComponent-ver-1.5.html) but it seems they are very basic , using those you can not able to customise your app same like iphone and android unless you have great knowledge of **openGl** for surface rending to customize your app (which is too much hectic and time consuming )

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if this will resolve your problem, but "Google Chart Tools" is worth trying. Check out the more details on the API here.

https://developers.google.com/chart/

It supports the below chart formats

1. Bar Charts Box chart
2. Candlestick chart
3. Compound Charts
4. Google-O-Meter Charts
5. GraphViz Charts
6. Pie Charts
7. Radar Charts
8. Scatter Charts
9. Venn Charts

Blackberry example using Google Chart API below

http://code.google.com/p/blackberry-google-chart-api/

And about your other problem of manipulating the events and showing effect on graph, is little tricky to handle here. You have to pay a decent amount of time to write your custom API for playing around the different events on your chat downloaded from google.  You have to use all your native API's for event handling.

But, again the if it doesn't serve your purpose then write your own library. But my experience there is not such library which provides charts with more customization as your requirement demands.

**EDIT-1**
Below link provides a basic idea of customizing your own Chart in native blackberry

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37205/Creating-a-XY-Chart-Plot-as-a-BlackBerry-Custom-Fi

Good Luck! Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanx for response, can you please suggest any native library that supports `BlackBerry OS >=5` ?

Comment: @Nirmal-thInkbeYond. As far I understand there is no native lib for generating charts. See my edit1 section with a link, explaining to create your own Charts using BB Native UI.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try `AFreeChart`. It's one of the few swing's `Jfreechart` ports for Android.
Check the project [here](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/) and some screenshots in this [link](http://afreechart.googlecode.com/svn/doc/screenshot/index.html).

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

For IOS

A most used one is core plot. http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

For android.

[AChartEngine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) is a charting library for Android applications. It currently supports the following chart types:

line chart,
area chart,
scatter chart,
time chart,
bar chart,
pie chart,
bubble chart,
doughnut chart,
range (high-low) bar chart,
dial chart / gauge,
combined (any combination of line, cubic line, scatter, bar, range bar, bubble) chart,
cubic line chart,

For BB;
http://amcharts.com/,
http://datamob.org/,
http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/253-useful-links-new-mobile-programmers-blackberry-sdk.html